# How to keep the data in the form after redirecting back from an exception

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, user-registration

I have a signup form in html(Thymeleaf template), and once I submit this form the following controller method is called:

```
@PostMapping("/signup_do")
public String register(Account account) {
    accountManagement.accountRegistration(account);

    return "Success";
}
```

Now accountRegistration is a service method which throws SignupFormException, which extends RuntimeException. This exception is handled in the same class as the controller with @ExceptionHandler anotation as follows:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value=SignupFormException.class)
public String handle() {
    return "redirect:/signup";
}
```

This returns an empty signup form back on facing an exception. But I want the values that are OK to remain populated.

If I could recieve the account object that was originally passed to the /signup_do controller into this exceptionhandler method, I could easily return model object back. But the following does not work:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value=SignupFormException.class)
public String handle(Account account) { //trying to get the account object
    System.out.println(account.getUsername());
    return "redirect:/signup";
}
```

The exception that is thrown is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [0] in public java.lang.String tv.redore.controller.AccountController.handle(tv.redore.entity.Account): No suitable resolver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but you can for example store this values in the session, which makes sense since you intent the values to trascend the request into the exception handling.

1. Store the information in the session when you recieve it in the controller:

   ```
   @PostMapping("/signup_do")
   public String register(HttpSession session, Account account) {
       session.setAttribute("account", account);
       accountManagement.accountRegistration(account);

       return "Success";
   }
   ```
2. Recover the account info in the exception handler and pass it to the model:

   ```
   @ExceptionHandler(value=SignupFormException.class)
   public String handle(Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {
       Account account = req.getSession().getAttribute("account");
       req.getSession().removeAttribute("account"); //Important, you don't want to keep useless objects in your session
       model.addAttriute(account.getUsername());
       return "redirect:/signup";
   }
   ```

You can even add the exception to the handler:

```
public String handle(Model model, HttpServletRequest req)
```

So that you've more info on what failed, and you know what to do accordingly.

Comment: I thought that sessions should be used to store a user's information on login and be destroyed on logout. This is a neat way of using it as well, that never crossed my mind. Is this some sort of hack, or is this the standard way of doing it?

Comment: @YeetCoder applications usually rely on frameworks like Spring Security to manage user access, which has many advantages like validating the requests recieved in the server. However this user management (user "sessions") are not to be confused with the session itself that any client has in any given server, even if that client has not yet logged in. This session is supposed to store any information relative to the client as a whole (and not just his login info and privileges if he has logged in; he has not to be logged in to have a session itself).